# Can you post in a facebook page, and a tweet on twitter with Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: facebook, azure, twitter, azure-mobile-services

I see that can be done authentication for the social networking, but I see if the libraries allow us to post on a facebook page and a twitter account.

Wanted to do it with mobile service, but no seeing other alternative, I think I'll have to do a service in PHP, and a ajax that responds from my mobile application.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Excuse me, I know my english is horrible ^^'. I'm using Facebook and Twitter authentication from Azure Mobile Service for Apache Cordova (More http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started-users/), and was asking if Azure Mobile Service supports "publish to a Facebook page and a Twitter profile"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to implement this by your own.
At first configure your mobile Service backend to query Facebook publish_actions (use Name: MS_FacebookScope | Value: publish_actions).
Then in .Net Backend add Facebook c# sdk and post to the wall with

```
var postParams = new
                {
                    message = "Hello World!"
                };
new FacebookClient(userAccessToken).Post("/me/feed", postParams);
```

Comment: @thorstem sorry, but the mobile service is in JavaScript. I forgot to mention several things